# SQLalchemy with nested class

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a rather complex object that takes a few other objects as its members. Something like this:

```
from engine import engine

Class Car(object):

    def __init__(self,engine_type):
        self.engine=engine(engine_type)
```

Is there a pain-free approach to map such nested definitions to a database, using SQLAlchemy for example?

Thanks for your help. I am learning SQLAlchemy and working with ORMS.

Comment: valiant effort at code formatting but I had to fix it up for you. Use four spaces in front of a block of code like I did. use the ` character for inline code.

Comment: I'd love to get an answer where `Engine` fields are mapped to the same tabe as `Car` fields, as they are related 1:1. Hibernate does this out-of-box.

Answer (score 1):

It's not much clear what you're trying to accomplish. If I understood, you are trying to define Car model with engine attribute that points to another Engine model, and by creating Car object with engine_type, the code should either:

- create Engine object with engine type if it doesn't exist
- load the Engine object  with engine type if exists

and then assign it to the Car object.

If so, you should do the following.

```
class Engine(object):
    def __init__(self, engine_type):
        self.engine_type

    @staticmethod
    def load(engine_type):
        return session.query(Engine)\
                      .filter(engine_type==engine_type).one()

class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, engine_type):
        try:
            engine = Engine.load(engine_type)
        except NoResultsFound:
            engine = Engine(session_type)
            session.add(engine)
        self.engine=engine
```

You'll need to define to create the 'engine' relationship on the Car mapper yourself, and also you'll need code tweaking to enable scope of the session object where needed.

Comment: This would get complicated soon if subcomponents of engine need to be loaded the same way. So with an ORM, I can't simply have complex nested relationships?

Comment: For example, say engine has a cylinder object member. And you want to list cars with different number of cylinders. (say engine has a list of cylinder objects, [cylinder1, cylinder2,...]. Is making everything in a model like this persistent as hard as it seems? Or should I just attempt to define the car model at one layer.)

Comment: I don't think it will be a problem if you wan't to realate the Engine model with a Cylinder model, in your case one Engine to many Cylinders, as I understand. You can later get the car list with the respect to cylinders with ease. If you can give me specific aspects of Engine-Cylinder rel and what car list you want to load, I can modify the code to help you.

Comment: I am confused. Let me think about what you did above more. As I understand, I need to store each object X and then if another object has X as a member, it has to try to load it, or create it if it doesn't exist, and then add it to the session when it is created to be stored. In your code, how would a Car object be loaded later from the database? Would its engine member also get loaded automatically?

Comment: You are correct. The Car object can be loaded by querying the session. You can choose if its engine is loaded eagerly (queried from db at the same call), or lazily (queried only when it is needed, that is, accessed as the attribute from the Car). You can use this article of mine to learn more about relationships and reflection: http://petrushev.wordpress.com/2010/06/16/reflective-approach-on-sqlalchemy-usage/